# ValueError: reading array data - while loading pickle file using joblib

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pickle, joblib

I am trying to load a pickle file which i created using `joblib.dump()`

The dumping code looks like:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib

with open('sample.pickle','wb') as f:
    joblib.dump([x,y],f)
```

This works fine and my sample.pickle is saved successfully. But when i try to load this file:

```
with open('sample.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    x, y = joblib.load(f)
```

I get the following error:

`ValueError: EOF: reading array data, expected 1200 bytes got 0`

The full error log looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "model.py", line 16, in <module>
vec_x, vec_y = joblib.load(f)
File "C:\Users\acer_pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 568, in load
obj = _unpickle(fobj)
File "C:\Users\acer_pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 508, in _unpickle
obj = unpickler.load()
File "C:\Users\acer_pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 1050, in load
dispatch[key[0]](self)
File "C:\Users\acer_pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 341, in load_build
self.stack.append(array_wrapper.read(self))
File "C:\Users\acer_pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 184, in read
array = self.read_array(unpickler)
File "C:\Users\acer_pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 135, in read_array
read_size, "array data")
File "C:\Users\acer_pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle_utils.py", line 646, in _read_bytes
raise ValueError(msg % (error_template, size, len(data)))
ValueError: EOF: reading array data, expected 1200 bytes got 0
```

By the way, i am very new to dumping and pickling.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using this library https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle ?

Comment: i used pickle earlier but then i was getting memory error when dumping the pickle file then i moved to joblib and everything was fine untill i tried to load it. Thank you for replying btw.

Comment: I got this working using just `pickle` instead. I’m not familiar with `joblib`.

Comment: when i used pickle it showed me memory error. Any solution for that?